# show json different field in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

my code showing the image and title and summary for all json file entries all what i need to show the image , title and summary to the first entry only and will show title to other entries.

please advise.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {

var entries = [];
var dmJSON = "http://localhost:8080/Newfolder/test.json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.summary + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
 });

});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
<thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    <th>Location</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what you're asking but I take it as you want First Name in the first table cell and first name and ID in the second.

```
var cutName = f.user.username.indexOf( ' ' ),
firstName = f.user.username.substr( 0, cutName == -1 ? 0 : cutName ),
tblRow = "<tr><td>" + firstName + "</td><td>" + firstName + " " + f.id + "</td><td>" + f.message + "</td><td> " + f.location + "</td><td>" + f.at + "</td></tr>";
```

Basically, use indexOf( ' ' ) to find the space after the first name. If the user only has one name (no space) then it returns -1 otherwise it is the index of the space. Then use substr to cut out the name.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: am asking to show in the first row only first name of the first item in the json file and for the other items it will show the first name and id

Comment: dose it make seance ?